# Nagle's algorithm is turned on or off with Play framework/Netty?

Tags: java, playframework, netty

I want to know that whether nagle's algorithm is turned on or off with Play Framework/Netty. If it is turned on by default in Play Framework/Netty how can i turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the frameworks you mention but the Nagle algorithm can be controlled (usually) by :

> For this reason, TCP implementations usually provide applications with an interface to disable the Nagle algorithm. This is typically called the TCP_NODELAY option.

see [Nagle Algorithm on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm)

Comment: i know that but i want to know that whether play framework turned it on or off as play framework uses netty as a web server.

Comment: I am not sure about the defaults in Play as I have never used it. I see in netty you can set it yourself